# Why the array is undefined?

Tags: javascript

In following code snippet why I see undefined logged?However if I separate  call to range method and store in some local variable then perform `foreach` ,it works fine.

```
    var range = function (max) {
        var result = [];
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index <= max; index = index + 1) {
            result.push(index);
        }
        return result;
    };


   var arr=  range(100).forEach(function (number, index,array) {
        if (number % 3 == 0) {
            array[index] = "c";
        }
    });

    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Because `Array.prototype.forEach` returns nothing.

Comment: Store `range(100)` in `arr`, then `forEach` over `arr`. `forEach` doesn't return anything thus undefined: https://jsfiddle.net/wj7akeh8/

Comment: I think you wanted [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not `forEach`. For `map`, you should *return* the new value from the function instead of updating `array[index]`. Look at the documentation for some examples.

Comment: Thanks Andrew !Yeah I should have used map instead forEach.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `forEach` function returns undefined. Have a look at the `map` function instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach